# GES ghe-repl-setup replica node cannot be reached over SSH and is not marked offline

Tags: github-enterprise

I'm setting up a new replica for a GES primary that has never been replicated.  Followed all instructions with no problems until I run ghe-repl-setup.  This almost completes successfully, but fails right at the end on 'validating configuration' stating (on the replica node itself) that the replica node cannot be reached over ssh.

I have tested ssh connectivity from the primary to the replica on port 122 directly, and vice versa; all works as it should.  Partway through the ghe-repl-setup it actually connects to the primary over ssh and pulls keys over, so it can connect.  I have trawled every GES HA document I can find, there's no mention of this error.  Anyone else seen it?

This is the exact setup output (domain names and ip addresses redacted):

admin@github-domain-replica:~$ ghe-repl-setup github.domain
Error: Can't configure replication with the GitHub Enterprise Server hostname. Please configure with the primary's IP address.

admin@github-domain-replica:~$ ghe-repl-setup xx.xx.xx.xx
Verifying ssh connectivity with xx.xx.xx.xx ...
Connection check succeeded.
Updating Elasticsearch configuration ...
Elasticsearch isn't listening on tcp/9200.
Copying license and settings from primary appliance ...
Syncing Actions state files and certificates (if applicable) from primary appliance ...
--> Importing SSH host keys...
--> The SSH host keys on this appliance have been replaced to match the primary.
--> Please run 'ssh-keygen -R xx.xx.xx.xx; ssh-keygen -R "[xx.xx.xx.xx]:122"' on your client to prevent future ssh warnings.
Copying custom CA certificates from primary appliance ...
Validating configuration
Cluster node github-domain-replica (xx.xx.xx.xx) cannot be reached over SSH and is not marked offline
admin@github-domain-replica:~$

I expected the configuration validation to succeed, and finish, so that I could then start replication.